# Returning the data type of columns in a generic C# class

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, generics, code-conversion

I am trying to convert the following piece of java code to C# and I am getting stuck at the point where I need to get the data type of the column. I am not too sure about the functions or procedure calls that I would be using.

***.NET Code***

```
namespace Workflow.DataTypes
{
    [Serializable]
    public class DataColumn1
    {
        private Type _dataTypes = null;
        private string _columnName = null;
        private string _defaultValue = null;

        public DataColumn1(string columnName, Type dataType)
            : this(columnName, typeof(string), null)
        {
        }

        public DataColumn1(string columnName, Type dataType, string defaultValue)
        {
            SetColumnName(columnName);
            SetDataType(dataType);
            SetDeafultValue(defaultValue);
        }

        public string GetDefaultValue()
        {
            return _defaultValue;
        }

        public bool IsDefaultValueDefined()
        {
            return _defaultValue != null && _defaultValue.Trim().Length > 0;
        }

        public void SetDeafultValue(string def)
        {
            _defaultValue = def;
        }

        public string GetColumnName()
        {
            return _columnName;
        }

        public void SetColumnName(string columnName)
        {
            this._columnName = _columnName;
        }

        public Type GetDataType()
        {
            return _dataTypes;
        }

        public void SetDataType(Type types)
        {
            this._dataTypes = _dataTypes;
        }

        public void SetDataType(string type)
        {
            try
            {
                SetDataType(type != null ? typeof (Type) : typeof (string));
            }
            catch (ArgumentException e)
            {
                // to do JavaUtils.enumToList(DataTypes.class)
                throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported data type: " + type + ". Supported types: " );
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return GetColumnName() + "[" + GetDataType() + "]" + (IsDefaultValueDefined() ? " (" + _defaultValue + ")" : "");
        }
    }
}
```

All I am looking for is how to return the column name and its data type. Thank you for taking the time to read through.

Comment: It should simply return the column name with the datatype and default value. you can ignore the GetName(). In java it will return the datatype name i.e string,int but foe now we can ignore it.

Comment: The equivalent of `Class.getName()` in Java is `Type.FullName` in C#. The rest of your question appears to be just "how do I write this in another language" and is really outside the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: I agree, but this is something I have been trying for almost 6 hours now and am getting no where. Hence I thought I'd ask the experts for some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's what you were asking for, but if you need a type's name, use

```
//short class name
typeof(T).Name
//full name with namespace
typeof(T).FullName
//namespace only
typeof(T).Namespace
```

`typeof(T)` is resolved at compilation, but if you want to get it dynamically at runtime, use `object.GetType()` for that.

**EDIT**

Ok, I see some mistakes in your code:

```
    public void SetColumnName(string columnName)
    {
        this._columnName = _columnName;
    }
```

should be

```
    public void SetColumnName(string columnName)
    {
        this._columnName = columnName;
    }
```

same with

```
        this._dataTypes = _dataTypes;
```

which should be

```
        this._dataTypes = dataTypes;
```

basically you were reassigning the same values in those methods, ignoring objects sent as parameter. And this will definately won't work:

```
public void SetDataType(string type)
{
    try
    {
        SetDataType(type != null ? typeof (Type) : typeof (string));
    }
```

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve here, but `typeof(Type)` is `Type`, which I doubt you intended to use. Also, `typeof(string)` will return the type of string class, not the object send in parameter. `typeof(type)` (an object sent in parameter) will also return you a string type, because that's the parameter type. Try to avoid confusing names, that are similar to keywords, especially when moving from Java to C#, because standard naming convention can trick you out.

Comment: My apologies for not clearly mentioning what I am after. I am looking to return the list of columns and their data types from the above C# Code.

Comment: I do not understand. You've got some custom column class, where do you want to get the column list from?

Comment: This is part of a big library of codes that I am converting to C#. The column list comes from the data set.

Comment: But where is it in your code? You're showing us whole class and not mentioning which part of it you cannot rewrite in C#. You asked how to return your data type of your column - that's what `GetDataType()` does. What's wrong with it? Your question is unclear.

Comment: SetDataType(type != null ? typeof (Type) : typeof (string)); Tarec: is this correct. Here i am nor sure if typeof(Type) is right.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `.GetType().FullName` or with `.GetType().Name` if you do not want the namespace.

Comment: Thanks it helped. GetType().Name